# Does Chicken Scheme have an equivalent to Perl's $0?

Tags: scheme, command-line-arguments, getmodulefilename, chicken-scheme

How can I reliably get the script name in Chicken Scheme?

It seems that -ss eats up the script name, so it's not visible unless I use dot slash to run my scripts.

scriptedmain.scm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env csi -q

(display (command-line-arguments))
(display "\n")
(exit)
```

Trace:

```
$ ./scriptedmain.scm 
(-q ./scriptedmain.scm)
wonko:Desktop andrew$ csi -ss scriptedmain.scm 
()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a late response, so may not be of use to the original poster. But to any others who may come across this question, the simple answer is to use the parameter:

```
(program-name)
```

This should return the correct name for all situations. [Docs here.](http://api.call-cc.org/doc/chicken/parameters/program-name)

Comment: Better late than never. Thanks dude!

Comment: My latest version works for all cases except compiled. For some reason, it just sits there.

Comment: @mcandre : Not sure what you mean by "all cases except compiled". I looked at your example scriptedmain.scm below - with program-name, and it works as an interpreted script, or as a compiled native executable. BTW, I wouldn't bother with that scaffolding (bash -> csi). Its not really needed#!/usr/bin/env chicken-scheme
#!/usr/bin/csi -s

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't bother with that scaffolding (bash -> csi). Its not really needed.

Put this in your ~/.csirc:

    (register-feature! 'in-repl)

Start your scripts with either:

    #!/usr/bin/env chicken-scheme
    #!/usr/bin/csi -s


And end them with the following block:

    (cond-expand
      (in-repl
     ; do something here)
      (else
        (main (command-line-arguments))))

Now your code will just work, whether you load the file into the repl and interactively develop, execute the file as a script through the interpreter, or compile it into a native executable and run it.

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting. I guess the comments don't respect inline code :(

Comment: I'll remove the bash -> csi scaffolding as soon as I can get this working in compiled mode. For some reason, on my system the compiled version never runs `(main)`.

Answer (score 1):

`(argv)` should do the job. Example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/csi -script

(display (argv)) (newline) (exit)
```

prints `(/usr/local/bin/csi -script ./test.scm)`

Comment: Almost! You have to add code for the special case where the script is compiled with csc; then the program is (list-ref (argv) 0).

Comment: With "script" i mean "not compiled". There are other solutions to distinguish between interpreted and compiled programs.

Answer (score 1):

scriptedmain.scm will run (main) and print the program name in the following cases:

Run from the interpreter:

```
csi -ss scriptedmain.scm
```

Run from the interpreter using shebangs:

```
./scriptedmain.scm
```

Compiled:

```
csc -o scriptedmain scriptedmain.scm
./scriptedmain
```

Added to [GitHub](https://github.com/mcandre/scriptedmain/blob/master/scriptedmain.scm).

```
#!/bin/sh
#|
exec csi -ss $0 ${1+"$@"}
exit
|#

(define (main)
    (display (format "Program: ~a\n" (program-name)))
    (exit))

(if (not (equal? (program-name) "csi"))
    (main))
```